# include header and footer from parent directory but not showing css

Tags: php, html, css

In my project directory looks like this: images, css, html(store header and footer.html..)...index.php. When viewing it on browser(`http://localhost/project1`), it works greatly.

Then I created new folder called: member. In this folder, i also has index.php. In that index file, I include('../html/header.html') and include('../html/footer'). When i view it on browser:(`http:// localhost/project1/member/`)It only showing html markup of header and footer but not styling?

Do i need to copy whole css folder from parent directory to member? Is there anyway to just link it from parent instead of copy whole css?

Comment: You should try to see the source code from your browser to see if the css file is reachable. If not, I think you should copy the css folder (as the laziest way).

Comment: I guess, your css file reference is located in the header? In that case you should reference your css files with an absolute path to be able to access them from everywhere.

Comment: For now, when you add the CSS file in your HTML, make sure you provide a full, absolute path - `<link href='http://localhost/project1/css/somefile.css'>`

You'll need to learn about relatives, and absolute paths first, then learn about virtual hosts once you're ready to take this a step further. With virtual hosts, you can set up your local project to be accessible as if it were on the internet: `http://project1.dev/` and then you can start using relative paths.

Comment: @ninty9notout including the protocol to the url is a bad idea!

Comment: It's only a bad idea if you're using assets from a protocol (eg `https`) which is different to your sites protocol (eg `http`). This is why CDN assets doesn't have protocols. For local stuff such as this is generally safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the way you're linking your css file in your header.html file. For example if your css folder is in the root of your project folder, and your css file is cssFile.css try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/project1/css/cssFile.css">
```

Comment: Never include the protocol! It will break your secure site if you decide to run https later.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute URLs, not relative URLs, to get to the CSS files. Relative URLs are interpreted by the browser. It doesn't know anything about the locations of the include files on the server, it just interprets these URLs based on the URL of the page that it loaded the HTML from.